# JVM memory profiling when multiple applications are running on the same JVM

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, jboss, jvm

I am running a Web Based Java application on JBOSS and OFBIZ. I am suspecting some memory leak is happening so, did some memory profiling of the JVM on which the application along with JBOSS and OFBIZ are running. I am suspecting garbage collection is not working as expected for the application.

I used VisulaVM, JConsole, YourKit, etc to do the memory profiling. I could see how much heap memory is getting used, how many classes are getting loaded, how many threads are getting created, etc. But I need to know how much of memory is used only by the application, how much by JBOSS and how much by OFBIZ, respectively. I want to find out who is using how much memory and what is the usage pattern. That will help me identify where the memory leak is happening, and where tuning is needed.

But the memory profilers I ran so far, I was unable to differentiate the usage of each application separately. Can you please tell me which tool can help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with Java since the Java runtime has no clear way to say "this is application A and this is B".

When you run several applications in one Java VM, you're just running one: JBoss. JBoss then has a very complex classloader but the app you're profiling is actually JBoss.

To do what you want to do, you have to apply filters but this only works when you have a memory leak in a class which isn't shared between applications (so when `com.pany.app.a.Foo` leaks, you can do this).

If you can't use filters, you have to look harder at the numbers to figure out what's going on. That means you'll probably have to let the app server run out of memory, create a heap dump and then look for what took most of the memory and work from there.

The only other alternative is to install a second server, deploy just one app there and watch it.

Answer (score 0):

You can install and create Docker containers, allowing you to run processes in isolation. This will allow you to use multiple containers with the same base and without having to install the JDK multiple times. The advantage of this is separation of concerns- Every application can be deployed in a separate container. With this, you can then profile any specific application running on the JVM because each namespace is provided with a completely isolated application's view of the operating environment, including process trees, network, user ids and mounted file system.

Here are a couple of resources for Docker:

1. [Deploying Java applications with Docker](http://blogs.infosupport.com/deploying-java-applications-with-docker/)
2. [JVM plus Docker: Better together](http://www.infoworld.com/t/java-programming/jvm-plus-docker-better-together-246535)
3. [Docker](https://www.docker.com/)

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Wow! I didn't know something like this exists! Thanks.Let me try to install it and use it. I will keep you updated.

Comment: Kewl! :0) Please let me know how it turns out!!

Answer (score 0):

Another good tool to use to find java memory leaks is [Plumbr](https://plumbr.eu). you can try it out for free, it will find the cause for the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError and even shows you the exact location of the problem along with solution guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

I explored various Java memory profilers, and found that YourKit can give me the closest result. In YourKit dashboard you can get links to individual classes running. So, if you are familiar with the codebase, you will know which class belongs to which app. You click on any class, you will see the CPU, Memory usage related to that. Also, if you notice any issues, YourKit can help you trace back to the particular line of the code in your source java files!

If you add YourKit to Eclipse, clicking on the object name in the 'issue area', will highlight the code line in the particular source file, which is the source of the problem.

Pretty cool!!